# Check if item exists in XML with AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, find, nodes

So I am pulling in this XML data using AS3 and storing it as myXML:

```
<Questions>
    <id>1</id>
    <question>
    This is question 1.
    </question>
</Questions>
<Questions>
    <id>3</id>
    <question>
    This is question 3.
    </question>
</Questions>
```

Now I want to check if an id is found within that XML. I am currently using this, but it always traces "NOT FOUND" -

```
for (var i: Number = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    if (myXML.Questions.(@id == i).length() > 0) {
        trace("FOUND")
    } else {
        trace("NOT FOUND");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no loop necessary. Vesper solution would work but in theory is very expensive and slow. PO was also pretty close but he's using @id as if the id element was an attribute. The solution is simply:

```
var result:XMLList = xml.Questions.(id == 1);
```

You either got a valid XMLList or you don't but that's all it takes.

Also do not use that code logic:

```
if(xml.Questions.(id == 1).length() > 0)
```

It creates an unnecessary additional xml search since if true you would then have to call "xml.Questions.(id == 1)" again to get the list. Instead call it and store the result first, then check the length if you wish so.

Answer (score 0):

With this XML your `Questions` should be an array internally, that is, `trace(myXML.Questions.length())` should return more than 1, so you are to iterate through `myXML.Questions` and check the node's `id` to be equal to your `i`.

```
for (var i: Number = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    var b:Boolean=false;
    for (var j:int=0;j<myXML.Questions.length();j++) {
        if (myXML.Questions[j].id==i) b=true;
    }
    if (b){
        trace(i,"FOUND")
    } else {
        trace(i,"NOT FOUND");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven been using AS3/XML for a while, but I think if you want to find **any** id (regardless of the number), you could try:

```
myXML.Questions.id.length() > 0
```

As to why it always traces NOT FOUND in your code, it's because the @ sign it's for attributes, not for elements. So it's trying to find:

```
<Questions id=1>
    ...
</Questions>
```